# Rust http crate create a request with post parameters

Tags: http, rust

I have this;

```
Request::builder()
 .method(http::Method::POST)
 .uri("/create_mapping")
 .body()
```

And I want to add POST parameters into the `body()`. Say something like a=1&b=2.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way seems to be to use `from_urlencoded` and do something like:

```
let encoded = form_urlencoded::Serializer::new(String::new())
            .append_pair("a", "1")
            .append_pair("b", "2")
            .finish();
```

and then create the body like this: `Body::from(encoded)`